# Choosing of a certain camera in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I had several cameras connected to my PC. In my applicaion I need to choose one of them. But I couldn't find how to do this. Is there any function for listing all connected cameras?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471938/detect-the-number-of-webcams-cameras-on-pc-with-opencv

Comment: @m47h And if I need the list of cameras' names, what shall I do?

Comment: opencv doesnt provide any methods for this. But to list the names you can try these two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286223/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-windows-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c

Answer (score -1):

```
CvCapture* capture;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
```

cvCaptureFromCAM will allow you to choose different cameras- start at 0. Then just take notes regarding which camera corresponds to which number.

Comment: I know this, the question is in that how to find what camera has a certain number?

Comment: This is not the way it is done today, use [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) instead